# Why did the D3 link labels stop working

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following code that used to place the link name from my json data on my node links.

```
// Append text to Link lines
var linkText = vis.selectAll(".gLink")
.data(json.links)
.append("text")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("x", function (d) {
    if (d.target.x > d.source.x) { return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2); }
    else { return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2); }
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
    if (d.target.y > d.source.y) { return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2); }
    else { return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2); }
})
.style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function (d) { return d.linkName });
```

The json data looks like this

```
var json = {
"nodes": [
{ "name": "Fabby MONDESIR", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635099", "ChartComments": "In Jail", },
{ "name": "ADNES D BRONSON", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635199", "ChartComments": "Armed", },
],
"links": [
   { "source": 0, "target": 1, "linkName": "FCC", "value": 8 },
   { "source": 0, "target": 2, "linkName": "Arr", "value": 10 }
   ]
}
```

the above json was static.  I am now trying to pull the data from SQL Sever with a stored procedure and wanted to use the primary key in the data base as the source and target in the links.  So I modified the json and it now looks like this. Note this is snippet of the json I ynderstand there is no 3rd subject in the nodes to work with the 1 to 3 link in the link data.

```
var json = {
"nodes": [
{ "sId": "1", "name": "Fabby MONDESIR", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635099", "chartComments": "Chart Comments"},
{ "sId": "2", "name": "ADNES D BRONSON", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635098", "chartComments": "Chart Comments" }
],
   "links": [
   { "source": "1", "target": "2", "linkName": "FCC",},
   { "source": "1", "target": "3", "linkName": "Arr",}
   ]
 }
```

To get this modification to work I had to add this piece of code:

```
var nodeMap = {};
   json.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.sId] = x; });
   json.links = json.links.map(function(x) {
       return {
           source: nodeMap[x.source],
           target: nodeMap[x.target]
          };
   });
```

The linking works properly but for some reason the link text is no longer shown on the lines.  I can't figure out why this has caused the link text to stop working the json data is still able to make the correct associations and draw the lines so does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  No other changes were made and if I revert back to the original json structure and remove the nodeMap code everythink works again.

Thanks
Perry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct the problem I had to map the linkName as well and the source and target. So the working code now looks like this

```
var nodeMap = {};
json.nodes.forEach(function (x) { nodeMap[x.SubjectID] = x; });
json.links = json.links.map(function (x) {
    return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        linkName: x.linkName
```

Answer (score 0):

The text should be coming from linkName but you do not include this when you map json.links:

currently:

```
 json.links = json.links.map(function(x) {
       return {
           source: nodeMap[x.source],
           target: nodeMap[x.target]
          // add linkName when mapping//
          };
    });
```

Comment: okay if I understand your solution then I should edit the above code by adding another line that would read linkName: nodeMap[x.linkName]

Comment: Hey Stacey I made the modification above and still no link labels.  I guess I did not understand your suggestion.  Did I miss something?

Comment: No it is what I suggested, so strange it doesn't work. When you map the data, are you positive it maps it correctly? Can you output the map to the console and see what you get?

Comment: Yep it maps correctly and shows the correct node linking.  FYI I got this solution from [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013_02_01_archive.html) after going back and looking at it a little closer it seems to just assign my sId to the original zero based node index and does not contain any info on the json links.  That is what makes it so strange it would cause this problem with the link names.  Thanks for taking you time to help out.

Comment: No probs glad you got it sorted

Comment: Stacey your first answer was correct I just had to get the syntax correct to map the linkName the correct syntax was linkName: x.linkName